# Namespaces equivalence and deprecation in OWL/RDF

Tags: namespaces, rdf, owl

I am creating an ontology based on OWL/RDF/RDFS. My first ontology schema has namespaces as :

@prefix abc: https://example.com/a#

I want to change the namespace the next version of the ontology as

@prefix def: https://example-new.com/b#

But I dont want the previous users of the ontology to be affected at all. I was thinking if there is a way to define equivalent namespaces, and classify that the first name space will be deprecated. I am not sure if there is any provision in the OWL/RDF or even Dublin-core to so do.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A namespace declaration isn't part of an OWL ontology, but some serialization specific. I don't see how you should be able to annotate the namspace declaration.

Comment: @Sidd, there exists the [`owl:priorVersion`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Ontology_Annotations) annotation property, but I'm not sure this is what you want.

Comment: @AKSW I did not know if that was possible, may be there are other options to resolve the same issue.

Comment: @StanislavKralin doesnt owl:priorVersion only link the pervious version of an ontology, which may not necessary link equivalence between namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this at the namespace level but you can declare all old classes and properties as equivalent to the new ones; you'd keep the old IRIs in the equivalent axioms and declaration axioms only. Then any third part that uses a reasoner would be able to run queries just as before; parties not using a reasoner would have to rewrite their queries following equivalent axioms (something that they might already be doing for other similar use cases).

Comment: Thanks. I have thousands of classes. This will increase the file size and also maybe the performance on the reasoner side. I might have to maintain these deprecated classes, which do not provide a whole lot of additional value. I was wondering if there are other options to tackle this issue?

Comment: The deprecated classes can be in a separate ontology, which imports your main ontology. Users of the old classes will have to endure the performance issues, if any, users if the new ones will not.